# Loop through a table using Cross apply and UNION ALL the results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, unpivot, cross-apply

Trying to write a query which will behave like a `foreach`

Query  :

```
select label ,NTILE(10) over(order by label ASC) Quartile INTO #labelTempTab from dbo.ReportFieldsLookup
```

The data will be like :

```
label   Quartile
-----   --------
la1         1
la2         1
la3         1
sa1         2
sa2         2
sq3         2
ha1         3
ha2         3
ha3         3
ka1         4
ka2         4
kas3        4
```

Continuation of Query :

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT * INTO #SetValuesTable  FROM svo_tbl

SET @sql = 'SELECT MNUM, Label , LabelValue ,[Property Type] FROM #SetValuesTable '
              +' CROSS APPLY ( VALUES '
              +  stuff(( SELECT ',('''+ replace(C.label,'''','"') + ''',' + quotename(C.label) + ')'   FROM #labelTempTab c WHERE c.Quartile = 1 group by label FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
              +' ) AS UPTab (Label , LabelValue);'

EXEC(@sql)
```

The above query will unpivot only for `Quartile = 1`
How can i make it work for 1 to n and union all the results.

data in #SetValuesTable will look like :

```
MNUM      la1   la2     la3   sa1  sa2      sq3    ha1     ha2    ha3   ka1   ka2 Property Type 
12         1     0      2      1    0       8       3       4      0     1     2    s
13         4     0      5      1    6       8       5       2      1     1     3    p
```

The result(Expected output) should look like

```
MNUM  Label LabelValue Property Type
12     la1     1          s
12     la2     0          s
12     la3     2          s
12     sa1     1          s
12     sa2     0          s
12     sa3     8          s

........

13     ka1     1          p
13     ka2     1          p
12     ka3     3          p
```

continuation of the query :

```
SET @sql = @sql + ' INNER JOIN dbo.ReportFieldsLookup tt ON tt.label = Label'
SET @sql = @sql + 'INNER JOIN dbo.SplitStrings_Ordered('''''09-404811,10-433495,10-433575,10-423789'''', ',') AS s ON #SetValuesTable.MNum = s.MNum ORDER BY s.[Index];
```

The above two statements are taking long time. Especially the Last inner join which is for sorting is taking long time. I think using cross apply might greatly reduce the execution time.

Comment: Please post your expected output

Comment: @BumbleBee From where you got `proprtytype` in result.  `data in #SetValues` doesn't have such column. Also am confused with which table is input and which one is expected output

Comment: sorry corrected the typo.

Comment: You want to Unpivot the data. Take a look at `UNPIVOT` http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3000/use-sql-servers-unpivot-operator-to-help-normalize-output/

Comment: I tried Unpivot but the data being so large it is taking long time. So I thought may be divide the tabel into sections and unpivot using cross apply and then join with ReportFieldsLookup might improve the performance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Cross Apply` to unpivot the result. Dynamic query query should be constructed in this format.

```
SELECT mnum,
       label,
       label_value,
       [Property Type]
FROM   #SetValuesTable
       CROSS apply(VALUES ('la1',la1),('la2',la2),('la3',la3),
                          ('sa1',sa1),('sa2',sa2),('sa3',sa3),
                          ('ha1',ha1),('ha2',ha2),('ha3',ha3),
                          ('ka1',ka1),('ka2',ka2)) cs (label, label_value)
```

`Dynamic query` should be something like

```
DECLARE @label VARCHAR(max)='',
        @sql   NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT @label += '(' + '''' + label + ''',' + label + '),'
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT Isnull(label, '') label
        FROM   #labelTempTab)a

SELECT @label = LEFT(@label, Len(@label) - 1)

SET @sql= 'SELECT mnum,
             label,
             label_value,
             [Property Type]
    FROM   #SetValuesTable
           CROSS apply(VALUES ' + @label
          + ') cs (label, label_value) '

EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

**Note :** Since you are generating values list from `#labelTempTab` table make sure you have all the labels present in `#SetValuesTable` table

Comment: Thank you. NoDisplayName. For this entire query the input is a string of Mnums. I have couple more steps to accomplish on this query. this is where the query is really taking time to execute. 1) Join the above gotten result with ReportFieldsLookup TAble 2) The Munms in the final table should be in the order by the input was sent